# Logging big data I got memory limit error

Tags: laravel

In laravel 6 app sometimes I need to debug with loging some data

```
\Log::info('$taskAssignedToUser::');
\Log::info($taskAssignedToUserCollection);
```

and I got  memory limit error.
My question is are there some tools/pluging/scripts to wrap collection(or request)
to show not all all nested data, but maybe some top elements?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `$taskAssignedToUserCollection` string?

Comment: No, as example that can be db data collection or request

Comment: Try with `\Log::info(is_string($taskAssignedToUserCollection) ? $taskAssignedToUserCollection : json_encode($taskAssignedToUserCollection));`.